# Where should I put the state for two components that are only rendered together in the router component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, react-props

**Update: I put my solution at the bottom!**

I have two components that need to work with the same props, but they are only ever rendered together in the react-router which lives in the App component... is my only option to hold the state at that level?

Essentially on the click of a button in Component A, it needs to set the state (using a setState function that it was given as a prop). Component B needs to be able to use this data, but it also needs to be able to set it, so it would receive 2 props: the data and the setState function.

The App file is their shared parent via a React-router. That component currently has no state, and it feels weird to me to be putting this random small piece of state in there.

But I'm still learning, so maybe this is really common and my instincts are completely wrong on. After spending the last couple hours googling, I figured it was time to bring in the experts XD

**Edit:**

I should have also said this: They are both acting as containers/views. They are currently only rendered in my App.js like this (edited to remove noise):

```
App.js (which is serving as my router file):

function App() {

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/routeA" render={ () => 
          <ComponentA/>
      }/>


      <Route exact path="/routeB" render={ () => 
        <ComponentB/>
      }/>
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then I have the two container/view component files.

**Update:**

In the end, I changed the way my files are structured so that I had a middle man container. This is the structure I went with:

```
App.js (main router):

function App() {

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/LandingRouteForThisSectionOfMyApp" render={ () => 
          <BothComponentsContainer/>
      }/>
    </Switch>
  );
}

//NOTE: There is no "exact" in the Route above. This is important here
//because there are 2 <Route>s using this route. If I wrote "exact" 
//at this point, then it wouldn't render the next one. 

//BothComponentsContainer.js (the head of the operation but 
//also the second router):

function BothComponentsContainer() {

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/LandingRouteForThisSectionOfMyApp" render={ () => 
          <ComponentA/>
      }/>

//NOTE: Component A is the landing component for this section. 
//Here, we need the "exact" keyword. I believe this is because 
//by the time the router gets here, I don't want anything else 
//to be rendered with this component.

      <Route exact path="/LandingRouteForThisSectionOfMyApp/ComponentB" render={ () => 
          <ComponentB/>
      }/>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

With this structure, I can now put state and logic into the BothComponentsContainer. Maybe not the most elegant of solutions, but it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

if the application will be very large, you can use Redux, if it is a medium or small application you can use Contex Hook de react and if you only want to share a state between components you can do it by props. I leave you a basic example

```
// File in Routers folder
const route = () => {
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
}

// File in Containers folder
const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('')

  const handleState = (value) => {
    setState(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className='layout'>
      <ComponetA onHandleState={handleState} />
      <ComponetB onReadState={state} />
    </div>
  )
}

// Files in folder components
const ComponetA = ({ handleState }) => {
  return (
    <input placeholder='Search' onChange={(e) => handleState(e.target.value)} />
  )
}

const ComponetB = ({ state }) => {
  return <h1>result for {state}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Normally I would do it this way, but they'll never be rendered together and they need to have their own routes. I edited my question above to show the router and also clarify that each component is a container/view in itself. Sorry, I should have specified that initially ^_^'